# How can I search for the number in the array?

Tags: c

1. I have to get user input and search for the user input in the array
2. If there is the number that is exactly matching with user input then I have to display "The number you entered is in the array"
3. If there is no number matching in array then I'm required to display "The number you entered is not in the array"

but currently I am experiencing the wrong output, I have double checked that user input was in the array but the result displayed as "no number matching".

How can I solve this problem?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    void arrayresult(int arraylength[], int &input_num)
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (arraylength[i] == input_num)
            {
                printf("The number you entered is in the array");
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                printf("The number you entered is not in the array");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        int input_num;
        int arrayindex;
        int arraylength[10];
        int i = 0;

        srand(time(NULL));

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            arrayindex += 1;
            arraylength[i] = rand() % (99 + 1 - 11) + 11;
            printf("A[%d]: %d ", arrayindex, arraylength[i]);
        }


        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter the number you want to search: ");
        scanf("%d", &input_num);

        arrayresult(arraylength, input_num);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: for start `int arrayindex;` is not initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply,Your program tend to check only the first index of the arraylength with that input number. If its fails you are out of the for loop. Time to know about the uses of flag variable. If Flag is set, the number is already found, and don't wants to check again. If Flag is unset, the number is not found.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void arrayresult(int arraylength[], int input_num)
{   
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (arraylength[i] == input_num)
        {
            printf("The number you entered is in the array");
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }


    }
if (flag == 0)
        {
            printf("The number you entered is not in the array");
        }
}

int main(void)
{
    int input_num;
    int arrayindex = 0;
    int arraylength[10];
    int i = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arrayindex += 1;
        arraylength[i] = rand() % (99 + 1 - 11) + 11;
        printf("A[%d]: %d ", arrayindex, arraylength[i]);
    }


    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter the number you want to search: ");
    scanf("%d", &input_num);

    arrayresult(arraylength, input_num);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this might helps : )

Comment: Hello @VJAYSLN, `input_num` is being passed as an integer, but the function is defined to accept the address of  `input_num` (`void arrayresult(int arraylength[], int &input_num)`)....the definition of the function needs to be corrected as well. Secondly since `arrayindex` is declared as an automatic variable, it would be worthwhile to initialize it with a value (0 in this case)......

Comment: Hi @LilyAB, Thanks for your corrections. Eventhough, these corrections not impact on the ouputs, these may affect the standards.

Answer (score 1):

your logic to check-in array is wrong. try this

```
void arrayresult(int arraylength[], int input_num) {  
    bool isFound = false;

   // iterate over till you found the  number or reaches end of array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (arraylength[i] == input_num){
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
     }

     if(isFound == true) {
         printf("The number you entered is in the array");
      }else{
            printf("The number you entered is not in the array");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only conclude the number is not the list, after checking with all elements
remove else from for loop.

```
    else
        {
            printf("The number you entered is not in the array");
            break;
        }
```

write printf("not found") after the loop, and write return in if

Answer (score 0):

```
    void arrayresult(int arraylength[], int &input_num)
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (arraylength[i] == input_num)
            {
                printf("The number you entered is in the array");
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                printf("The number you entered is not in the array");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

in this for loop,if your input not match the arraylength[0],

then your method immediately print 'the number you entered is not in the array'

and then break the for loop,so you never get the chance to compare the rest of your array to input_num

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: by the way, your arrayindex never initialized

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void arrayresult(int arraylength[], int input_num)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (arraylength[i] == input_num)
        {
            printf("The number you entered is in the array");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("The number you entered is not in the array");
}

int main(void)
{
    int input_num;
    int arraylength[10];
    int i = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arraylength[i] = rand() % (99 + 1 - 11) + 11;
        printf("A[%d]: %d ", i + 1, arraylength[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter the number you want to search: ");
    scanf("%d", &input_num);

    arrayresult(arraylength, input_num);

    return 0;
}
```